# Filtering a UserDefinedFunctionCollection using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

In the code below, is there a way I can filter the members of the `UserDefinedFunctionCollection` so I don't have to do the `if (!udf.IsSystemObject)` check inside the loop?

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

private void DebugSqlUserDefinedFunctions(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            Server svr = new Server(new ServerConnection(cmd.Connection));
            foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UserDefinedFunction udf in svr.Databases[cmd.Connection.Database].UserDefinedFunctions)
            {
                if (!udf.IsSystemObject)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(udf.Name);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
private void DebugSqlUserDefinedFunctions(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    Server svr = new Server(new ServerConnection(cmd.Connection));
    foreach (var udf in svr.Databases[cmd.Connection.Database].UserDefinedFunctions.Cast<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UserDefinedFunction>().Where(udf => !udf.IsSystemObject))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(udf.Name);
    }
}
```

May or may not require the .Cast<>()

Comment: That seems to be it, and yes the .Cast<>() was necessary - is that because the collection wasn't a System.Collections.Generic ?

Comment: @tbone Not quite; it's because the collection implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<UserDefinedFunction>`, so enumerating the collection yields `objects` which you need to cast.

Comment: Yes that's why:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx

The Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable) method enables the standard query operators to be invoked on non-generic collections by supplying the necessary type information. For example, ArrayList does not implement IEnumerable<T>, but by calling Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable) on the ArrayList object, the standard query operators can then be used to query the sequence.